# Why do(es) the ball(s) stick to the ground after an arbitrary amount of time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, physics

I have the following code which bounces multiple balls along the screen, making use of physics, and the gravity of jupiter divided by 10 for testing purposes.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//jupiter's gravity divided by 10 for testing purposes
g = 24.79/10;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 50;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 22.5;
bounciness = (1/2)
var spawnrate = 16;
var inertia = 0.00075;
var gravity = g/25;
players = []
then = new Date()/1000;
moved = false;
function getPosition(event){
 mouseX = event.clientX;
 mouseY = event.clientY;
 if(moved == false){
  update();
  moved = true;
 }
}
function addCircle(){
    players.push({x: mouseX, y: mouseY, color: '#000000', radius: 10, velY: 0, velX: 2, jumped: false, jump: 0.02, max: 0});
}
first = new Date();
function update(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 t = new Date() - first;
 now = new Date() / 1000;
 if(now-then >= 1/spawnrate){
  then = now;
  addCircle();
 }
 for(var c = 0; c < players.length; c++){
  circle = players[c];
  circle.y+=circle.velY;
  circle.x+=circle.velX;
  circle.velX-=inertia;
  circle.velY+=gravity;
  if(Math.abs(circle.velY) > Math.abs(circle.max)){
   circle.max = circle.velY;
  }
  if(circle.y + circle.radius/2 > canvas.height){
   circle.velY*=-Math.sqrt(bounciness);
  }
  updateCircle(circle);
  if(circle.x > canvas.width){
   players.splice(c, 1);
  }

 }
        setTimeout(update, 10);
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
 ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
 ctx.stroke();
}

function updateCircle(player){
        ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, player.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", getPosition, false);
if(moved == true){
 update();
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Bounce</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

## If after running the code snippet you don't see the error, try moving the mouse around the screen arbitrarily.

However, after I move the mouse around, I notice that some of the balls seem to stick to the bottom of the screen.

[image]

I have been working on this for the past 8 hours, only to be dumbfounded. The code is relatively simple, so I don't think it's any obvious mistake.

### By the way, I am going to add a +500 bounty in 2 days

Comment: Well, you don't have perfectly elastic bouncing, and after a certain amount of time the balls have been robbed of all their vertical momentum. What is the part you don't understand?

Comment: @Asad look at the picture at the bottom, obviously even though the bounce height should only reach 3/4 of the previous height, that doesn't seem right...

Comment: I'm previewing your code in firefox and I'm not seeing the behavior you're describing. Could you specify what browser you're using and show us a snippet that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: Oh great. I'll try it on firefox in a sec, any idea why this is occuring?

Comment: Well like I said, I'm not seeing the problem happen at all, so I can't comment on why it could be happening. Are you by any chance putting your mouse at the bottom of the canvas?

Comment: @Asad nope, I'll try to take a video in a sec.

Comment: @Asad, check [this out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hLEExDZpChg&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: I've noticed a few things though. Why are you dividing the radius by 2 when you check the height? Also, if your ball falls sufficiently far below the border of the canvas in a single step, it is possible for its velocity to get flipped twice before it manages to go back above the border, resulting in an infinite loop of flipping velocities. You should set an absolute upward velocity and zero the height.

Comment: @Asad yes, but if I set an absolute upward velocity, the ball will keep bouncing without air resistance and I want it to be somewhat accurate.

Comment: By absolute I mean using `Math.abs`. See if you can you reproduce the issue with this code:https://gist.github.com/masaeedu/1f6f2d3f1fdff190ee7a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is the collison detection:

> ```
> if (circle.y + circle.radius/2 > canvas.height) {
>     circle.velY*=-Math.sqrt(bounciness);
> }
> ```

This just inverts the velocity, but does not adjust the position. Which means that when you drop your balls from certain heights, they can get stuck *in* the ground - they have entered it by a certain depth, but in the next frame their reduced velocity is no more enough to *take them out of the ground*, and gets inverted right again taking them a bit deeper in the ground…

You can solve this fairly easy by making sure that their vertical position never gets "negative", or even completely bounce the ball away from the ground:

```
var inGround = circle.y + circle.radius - canvas.height;
if (inGround >= 0) {
    circle.velY *= -Math.sqrt(bounciness);
    circle.y -= 2*inGround;
}
```

Try the updated snippet demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//jupiter's gravity divided by 10 for testing purposes
g = 24.79/10;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 50;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 22.5;
bounciness = (1/2)
var spawnrate = 16;
var inertia = 0.00075;
var gravity = g/25;
players = []
then = new Date()/1000;
moved = false;
function getPosition(event){
 mouseX = event.clientX;
 mouseY = event.clientY;
 if(moved == false){
  update();
  moved = true;
 }
}
function addCircle(){
    players.push({x: mouseX, y: mouseY, color: '#000000', radius: 10, velY: 0, velX: 2, jumped: false, jump: 0.02, max: 0});
}
first = new Date();
function update(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 t = new Date() - first;
 now = new Date() / 1000;
 if(now-then >= 1/spawnrate){
  then = now;
  addCircle();
 }
 for(var c = 0; c < players.length; c++){
  circle = players[c];
  circle.y+=circle.velY;
  circle.x+=circle.velX;
  circle.velX-=inertia;
  circle.velY+=gravity;
  if(Math.abs(circle.velY) > Math.abs(circle.max)){
   circle.max = circle.velY;
  }
        var inGround = circle.y + circle.radius - canvas.height;
  if(inGround >= 0){
   circle.velY *= -Math.sqrt(bounciness);
            circle.y -= 2*inGround;
  }
  updateCircle(circle);
  if(circle.x > canvas.width){
   players.splice(c, 1);
  }

 }
        setTimeout(update, 10);
}

function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2){
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
 ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
 ctx.stroke();
}

function updateCircle(player){
        ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, player.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", getPosition, false);
if(moved == true){
 update();
}
```

```css
#canvas{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Bounce</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, add `circle.y = canvas.height - circle.radius` inside the collision checking branch.

Comment: @Asad: Yeah, that's the simple solution, setting the balls height to zero and ignoring the depth it has already gone into the ground - that it would have bounced upwards again already.

Comment: One might even do `circle.y -= inGround /* before collision */ + inGround*Math.sqrt(bounciness) /* after collision */;`